# Authentication always return none even though username and password is correct with the database - DJANGO

Tags: django

Before that , i want to say that i already see for many solutions and it still not working , thats why i ask this question

So i try to make a login form and a login module , when i insert the username and password correctly -> i already copy the value from the database so it will same 100% ---> but authentication always return none

i already print the value into the cmd and what i put is the same as the value in database ..

this is the login.html

```
<div id="login-page">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-login" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID">
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <br>
           {% if messages %}
              <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <font color="red"><li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li></font>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
         
              <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" type="submit" href=""><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>          
              
          <hr>
          
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the views for login (i already modified the login) and register

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        print("yes")        
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(username)
        print(password)
        guest = User.objects.get(username=username)
        rolee= UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user_id = guest.id).role
        print(rolee)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
        print(user)
        if user: 
            if rolee == 'Business Analyst':
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/home/')
            elif rolee == 'Admin':
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/manageuser/')
            elif rolee == 'Manager':
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/approvallist/')
            elif rolee == 'Segment Manager':
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/approvallist/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"login.html",{"form":form})

def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)   
            clearPassNoHash = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            varhash = make_password(clearPassNoHash,None,'md5')
            user.set_password(varhash)  
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user            
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',
                          {'user_form':user_form,
                           'profile_form':profile_form,
                           'registered':registered})
```

models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username
```

Last one is : forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta():
         model = UserProfileInfo
         fields = ('role','description','address','phone','cell')
```

login before i modified

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            guest = User.objects.get(username=username)
            role = guest.role
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user is not None: 
                if role == 'Business Analyst':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/home/')
                elif role == 'Admin':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/manageuser/')
                elif role == 'Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
                elif role == 'Segment Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"login.html",{"form":form})
```

Note :

> 1. first i already use form.is_valid() -> but it keeps return not valid so i remove the form.is_valid() so i can authenticate directly , but it always says none
> 2. before i hash the password , my register password didnt hashed, and i search that authenticate need a hash password,  so i try hash with the django.contrib.auth.backend.md5hashers or something in the settings.py , and already hashed, and it still not working.
>
> 3.the role is in the different model

I hope someone can fix it , already try many ways and cant get it done .. thankyou for the help <3

Comment: So what is `AuthenticationForm`? Is that the `UserForm` itself (`from .forms import UserForm as AuthenticationForm`)?

Comment: @PedramParsian from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

Comment: @PedramParsian i think the problem is in the user = authenticate(username=username,password=password) not the form = AuthenticationForm

Comment: Are you using `make_password` to make hash password out of the raw password?

Comment: @PedramParsian yes ..

Comment: How did you change the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in settings? I think there is something wrong there. Also keep in mind that if you don't have any special use-case, you can stick to the default `PASSWORD_HASHERS` (don't include it in the settings) and have `make_password(clearPassNoHash)` instead.

Comment: @PedramParsian it can? because in the setting before didnt have password_hashers thats why i include it

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)

Comment: Yes, there is a default `PASSWORD_HASHERS` included (check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/))

Comment: @PedramParsian w8 i try haha

Comment: @PedramParsian still not working hmm cant login

Comment: You should create a _new_ user (because the hash algorithm has changed) as you change the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in the settings.

Comment: @PedramParsian already haha still not working

Comment: @PedramParsian already put the first login view before i modified it

Comment: @PedramParsian maybe you can check there's something wrong with it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot the issue, in your registration process, you are are using:

```
user = user_form.save(commit=False)   
clearPassNoHash = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
varhash = make_password(clearPassNoHash,None,'md5')
user.set_password(varhash)  
user.save()
```

Actually, the `set_password` will call the `make_password` itself, So you should do:

```
user = user_form.save(commit=False)   
clearPassNoHash = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
user.set_password(clearPassNoHash)  
user.save()
```

> This is how `set_password` is defined:
>
> ````
>     def set_password(self, raw_password):
>         self.password = make_password(raw_password)
>         self._password = raw_password ```
> ````

Comment: IT WORKS! THANKYOU , so the logic that i hash the password twice? thats why i cant login

Comment: @trytocode Yes, You were hashing the hashed password again! Glad to help.